# How to choose exact row in table while editing with angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating editable table, and while editing all rows became input fields, how to choose only one row that I'm clicking on?

This is a piece of my table

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
   <td>
      <span ng-if="!editing">{{item.username}}</span>
      <span ng-if="editing">
         <!-- If I use ng-if="editing && index == $index" than all other fields disappear -->
         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="item.username">
      </span>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div ng-if="!editing">
         <button ng-click="edit()" >Edit</button>
      </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.editing = false;
        $scope.index = "";
        $scope.edit = function(index) {
            $scope.editing = true;
            $scope.index = index;
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check that the index of the current item is not the item in edition while in editing mode:

```
<span ng-if="!editing || index!=$index">{{item.username}}</span>
<span ng-if="editing && index==$index">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="item.username">
</span>
```

See working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/805rt1wd/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this first rule I missed!

Answer (score 1):

pass index on click

try like this

```
<button ng-click="edit($index)" >Edit</button>
```

Or the object itself

```
<button ng-click="edit(item)" >Edit</button>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UWLFJ/216/)

Comment: Nothing of this helps :(   I've already tried.  Please see JsFiddle:  
http://jsfiddle.net/UWLFJ/214/    What is wrong?